# How to find grandchild tag according to class information in beautiful soup?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML page source. I am trying to find the first tag whose `class="title"` in tag `ais-InfiniteHits-item`.
I am using beautiful soup.

I am trying to find the tag that has the class `title` that is also a grandchild of a tag that has the class `ais-InfiniteHits-item`

I tried

```
soup.select(".ais-InfiniteHits-item > .title")
```

It did not work because this applies to child situation, meanwhile, it is a grandchild or grand grandchild in my case.

Comment: Mind adding a sample HTML or a URL to the site?

Comment: ```mydivs = soup.findAll("li", {"class": "title"})```?

Comment: You have confused the type/tag selector with the class. Replace li with what you have put against class and ensure the class is`title`

Comment: `mydivs` is in fact a list of bs4 objects, so you can only call `.findAll` on each element of it

Comment: if you're trying to find the tag that has the class `title` that is also a children of a tag that has the class `ais-InfiniteHits-item`, use a css selector- `.ais-InfiniteHits-item > .title`

Comment: @Chase I edited the title based on your suggestion. Besides, your method works for the child, but it could be the grandchild or grand grandchild in my case. Thanks

Comment: @JingGu for multiple levels of nesting use `.ais-InfiniteHits-item .title`